# USB Drives not showing up after Mac was sleeping

Tags: usb, external-disk

I am constantly encountering the following problem with my Mac(s). This has been happening with two different Macbook Pros (13" late 2011 and 13" 2017) with numerous MacOS versions, including the latest High Sierra.
In addition, this happens with various different USB pendrives.

[edit]

We are talking two different Macbooks here, i.e. the USB controller is hardly the problem. We are also talking about multiple, different USB pendrives, so the drives themselves are also not the problem.

With the new Macbook, I have to use a USB-C to USB-A adapter. Here, I use one of the brand "LPG" and one from Apple. The Problem persists with both adapter as well as with either one of them alone.

[/edit]

Obviously, this is not a problem with a specific system configuration, version, or hardware, but rather seems to be a problem of the OS itself.

Description:

I have a USB pendrive attached to a USB port of an external USB hub. The drive works fine, no problems. Then, I put my Mac to sleep and disconnect the Hub. When re-attaching the Hub at a later time, the drive won't be mounted automatically again. Actually, It doesn't even show up in the list of USB devices in the Disk Utility tool.

Interestingly, all other devices attached to the same hub (keyboard, mouse, ...) keep working just fine after reattaching the USB hub. Never had a single problem here.

Unplugging the pendrive and pugging it in again won't help, even when plugging it into another USB port. But when the system is rebooted, the drive shows up again as if nothing happened.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: As a test, bypass the hub.  Plug the drive directly into the Mac.  Does the problem go away?

Comment: Is the hub powered?

Comment: @Allan: Can't do that, as it's a regular pendrive (USB-A), and my Mac only has 2 USB-C drives

Comment: @IconDaemon: It's powered, but works with and without power supply plugged in. Problem persists with both cases

Comment: You're just testing, disconnect whatever you have in the USBC port, like the hub.

Comment: Did that already too: USB-drive in the hub, hub connected to the Mac. Pendrive works.
Disconnect hub -> reattach hub -> doesnt work anymore. 
Disconnect drive from hub -> plug it in -> doesnt work. 
Restart computer -> works

Comment: @Allan : Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Try a different hub or a [USB-C to USB-A adapter](http://amzn.to/2BBPKZb).  I believe the issue is your hub, but to verify that theory, you have to test and to test, you may need additional equipment.  For the record, my theory is based on actual experience - I had an Anker hub that would reset my entire USB bus when I plugged in more than 1 item (two pen drives, for example).  Bypassing the hub confirmed the theory and attaching a new/different hub confirmed that.

Comment: I am trying with two different hubs that work perfectly with all other devices (keyboard, mouse, ...).
The hubs I am using are the orig. Apple USB-C to USB-A+HDMI+USB-C hub, the other one is a multihub with HDMI+network+USB-A+USB-C.
Both hubs work perfectly when plugged in alone as well as when plugged in together. There are NO problems with ANY other device connected to them. The ONLY problem are USB pendrive: MULTIPLE, DIFFERENT ONES.
As pointed out earlier, I also had this problem with my old MacBook pro (mid 2011). 
So I'm confident saying it is NOT the hub, and it is NOT the pendrive.

Comment: Can you see your USBs with while they are unmounted with `diskutil list`?

Comment: I have a similar problem, just with USB devices (mouse, keyboard) behind the hub AND a switch (which is also connected with my windows PC). After my mac went to sleep/awakes the devices are not detected. Current workaround is, that I switch through all 4 USB-C (MBP) ports and then do a SMC reset. So I can restart using all 4 ports again. On windows, there is a setting to force the system to search for USB devices and since then I fixed the problem on windows. Apple support could not help me either. It seems to be connected to the fact, that the hub is delivering the voltage instead of the mac.